# How to shrink images in an android app ?

Tags: android, image

I have around 100 images to be displayed in slide shows in an android app.

- What is the minimum optimum size that I should store in the drawable folders. I want to confirm with expert opinion that this is the right place to store these images.
- I have a two dimensional image array in the activity code to access these images - kind of hard coded. Please advise if this is the right track and the best way.
- Which type of images it is best to put here inside the app - png/... - so that the views are the best and the size not much inflated. The main crunch is to keep app size small. How can this be best achieved ?

Answer (score 2):

According to your question you have to use server images because if you will use 100 images from the drawable folder then your application size will be huge. because every images has a different high screen resolution.

Plus point of fetch image from the server using parsing, you will use image loader class which will be very efficient to display images.

Another option, you can also use SQLITE database in which you can store your image as a imagename , imagepath , byte array or as a bitmap images and retrieve it very easily.

Answer (score 1):

Use .png files. Use also https://tinypng.com/ to compress your images. It helps a lot!

edit:
Read also this tutorial about [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can read your drawables like this:

```
Field[] drawables = com.example.appname.R.drawable.class.getFields();
for (Field f : drawables) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Drawable." + f.getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This way you don't need any hardcoded array and updating is simpler. Also think of loading your images from some server instead embedding to application.

And yes, use PNG:s for best image quality.